# Rails 3 Gem Include

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I have made this gem: https://github.com/RLovelett/feedzirra-rails
I want to be able to include it like: `gem "feedzirra-rails", :git => "git://github.com/RLovelett/feedzirra-rails.git", :branch => "feedzirra-rails"`

However, Rails does not seem to be extending ActiveRecord::Base automatically. Though, if I call `require "feedzirra_rails"` inside of a model that uses `acts_as_feed` everything is fine.

Basically, I don't want to have to call require. I just want `acts_as_feed` available to all models automatically.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a railtie to the gem.  This will make it load automatically when you include the gem in your Gemfile.  Make sure you require the railtie in lib/feedzirra.rb

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Railtie.html